# Setting up a propel workspace

Tags: php, database, orm, propel

I'm trying to setup propel for the first time but I can't seem to get it configured right.

My workspace is like so:

> /var/www/prod/[project_name]/www
>
> /var/www/dev/propel
>
> /var/www/dev/projects/[project_name]/www

So I want to set this up so I can have propel generator will just be in `./dev/propel/` and only the files that are needed (runtime / build) will be in the `./[project_name]/www` that leaves all project configs in there own project folder `./[project_name]` so I can just build them from `./projects/[project_name]`.

if there is a better way of doing this, please let me know... is there any easy way to move `./dev/` to `./prod/`? or just do a CP then run the migration script?

Answer (score 1):

With the last Propel versions (1.6.x), you can use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) to manage your dependencies in your project. It's not an answer to your question **but** having a global Propel installation is not recommended at all, same thing for separating runtime and generator.

If both `dev` and `prod` own the same configuration, you can do a `cp`. But most of the time, it's recommended to generate files in `dev` **and** in `prod` as you can have different configurations. That's why having the full Propel lib in its project is a good idea.